# What does the "list name not defined" error mean in python?

Tags: python, scoping

I'm new to python, and I'm getting an error I can't figure out. 
The following script:

```python
def add_10(list_num):
    list_num = [1,2,3]                                                 
    list_add_10 = []
        for num in list_num:                     
                list_add_10.append(num + 10)
        print list_add_10
```

Returns the error:

```
 "NameError Traceback (most recent call last)

 <ipython-input-11-73c7e124d6d6> in <module>()
       4     for num in list_num:
       5         list_add_10.append(num + 10)
 ----> 6 print list_add_10
      NameError: name 'list_add_10' is not defined"
```

I think it's just a scope/indentation problem, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use four spaces or Ctrl+K to format your code

Comment: Well, yes. Your indentation is off.

Comment: Indent the `print list_add_10` line

Comment: I assume the ...: is not part of your actual code?

Answer (score 3):

```
def add_10(list_num):
    list_num = [1,2,3]                                                 
    list_add_10 = []
    for num in list_num:                     
        list_add_10.append(num + 10)
    print list_add_10
```

Your indentation is incorrect. The first four lines of the function should be dedented by four spaces as shown in my answer.